# Cypress: Intercept a route that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I am currently intercepting the `authorization.oauth2` request successfully, but what I would like to do then is to make a request to my localhost (A non-existing route in the application). However, when I do this, I get a 404 error.

Is there anyway to intercept a request to a route that doesn't exist?

```js
  cy.intercept('*authorization.oauth2*', req => {
    cy.request('POST', '/auth/intercept/handle');
    req.reply('');
  });

  // This route doesn't exist:
  cy.intercept('POST', '/auth/intercept/handle', req => {
    // Handle stuff
  });
```

This is the output of the request:

```
cy.request() failed on:

https://localhost:4200/auth/intercept/handle

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 404: Not Found

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx or 3xx.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: failOnStatusCode: false

-----------------------------------------------------------

The request we sent was:

Method: POST
URL: https://localhost:4200/auth/intercept/handle
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/8.1.0 Chrome/89.0.4328.0 Electron/12.0.0-beta.14 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "/",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "content-length": 0
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

The response we got was:

Status: 404 - Not Found
Headers: {
  "x-powered-by": "Express",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  "content-length": "161",
  "date": "Tue, 03 Aug 2021 19:57:39 GMT",
  "connection": "keep-alive"
}
Body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /auth/intercept/handle</pre>
</body>
</html>

Because this error occurred during a after each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Roles Page
```

Comment: The problem appears to be with the request on line 2 of your example rather than the intercept. When you request an endpoint that doesn't exist a 404 response is expected behaviour. What would you like to happen?

Comment: I want the intercept to catch the request and run the callback.

Comment: I found this in the docs: `cy.intercept() cannot be debugged using cy.request()! Cypress only intercepts requests made by your front-end application.`

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing a cy.intercept to make a post request from the cy intercept, try using cy.intercept to respond directly to your frontend with the data you want to include.
After all, the purpose of cy.intercept is to intercept requests to change data on the request and induce behaviors that we want to test in our frontend.

Try something like this:

```
const res = { message: true }

cy.intercept(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '*authorization.oauth2*'
    },
    res
)
```